# Handling exceptions with Tastypie

Tags: python, django, api, exception, tastypie

Ok, I,ve built my first API example using Django. I had this CSV file that I inserted into my database; then I creates my basic API system. Now I can output a JSON with 3 fields: title, image, description (as they were in the CSV). Perfect.

Now my question is pretty generic but conceptually relevant:

The image field is populated with urls but some of them are not correct. I mean not all of them are pointing to jpg, png or any other image file. I want my api system to output an error when accessing a resource that contains a bad url in the image field.

How can I handle this (and eventual other wrong fields)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you mean a csv (comma-separated value) file?

Comment: Yes  I always write it that way, it's stuck in my head. I meant CSV of course, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you're using the images, it's hard to say how to handle non-existing files.    If you want to throw an exception before the image is used, you can check to see if it exists, and throw one if it doesn't like so:

```
import os
path_to_file = 'my_image.jpg'
if not (os.path.exists(path_to_file) and os.path.isfile(path_to_file)):
    # This needs to be OSError (I think) before Python 3.3 (I think)
    raise FileExistsError('The file {} does not exist.'.format(path_to_file))
# do stuff with file if it exists
```

If you make your question more specific I can make this answer more specific.

Comment: Mmh I fear that I wasn't clear. I try to put it right: imagine a CSV file with three fields: title, image, description and many entries based on this shema. Now let's use tastypie to convert it to an API. Ok now if you go to different urls you get the various entries formatted as JSONs. Some of them, in the image field, have an url pointing to an actual image. Other in the image field have an url pointing to something that it's not an image(ex.: www.google.com). Ok I want my api to EXCLUDE those entries that doesn't point to an image!